# Error in PLSQL delete_document function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

This is my PLSQL function to delete a document. SQLdeveloper complains. I know VARCHAR should be replaced with VARCHAR2, I am aware of that. There's something more than that. Package specification is absolutely fine.

```
FUNCTION delete_document (p_da_document_id  IN  da_documents.da_document_id%TYPE)
RETURN VARCHAR
IS

  v_delete_status VARCHAR := 'N';

BEGIN

  DELETE FROM da_document_key_values
  WHERE da_document_id = p_da_document_id;

  DELETE FROM da_document_tags
  WHERE da_document_id = p_da_document_id;

  DELETE FROM da_documents
  WHERE da_document_id = p_da_document_id;

  COMMIT;

  SELECT COUNT(*) AS doc_count
  FROM   da_documents
  WHERE  da_document_id = p_da_document_id;

  IF (doc_count = 0) THEN
    v_delete_status := 'Y';
  END IF;

RETURN v_delete_status;

END delete_document;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realised a procedure above has not been ended correctly. END; was missing. My mistake.